# How to align xml views under each other and starting from the same point

Tags: android, xml

I designed the labels in red in the `layout.xml` to be placed under each other as shown,but to begin from the same starting point "the black line", this part i tried it but could not manage.

please see the xml file below.
I tried to change `layout_width` of each view labeled in red to be `match_parent` but this make the labels starts from the very left as if they are alignedToParentLeft. please let me know what should i add to the layout to have the views started from the black line?

xml:

```
<RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/reportRealtiveLayout02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical">
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/reportLocNameLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Name: "
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/reportLocNameValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/reportLocNameLabel"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/reportRealtiveLayout03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical">
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/reportLocLatLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Lat: "
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/reportLocLatValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/reportLocLatLabel"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/reportRealtiveLayout04"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical">
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/reportLocLngLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Lng: "
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/reportLocLngValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/reportLocLngLabel"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/reportRealtiveLayout05"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical">
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/reportTimeLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Time: "
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/reportTimeValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/reportTimeLabel"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

output_Image:
[image]

Comment: Try using a table layout

Comment: i would try it shortly and inform

Comment: glad to help... upvote would be another pleasure.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote `android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"` in each `RelaviteLayout`.

I will suggest you to remove that line of code. This code will automatically `center` its children. `center_vertical` is okay. But `Center` is not preferable. Instead you can also use following code.

```
android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many kinds of methods to solve this problem.

1,if the black line is a `ImageView`,you just set `reportRealtiveLayout02`      `layout_toRightOf` it. And set labels to be `alignedToParentLeft`.

2,It is more likely that the black line is not exist.So just set labels to be `alignedToParentLeft` and make their `margin_left` a suitable number.

3,I wonder how you make "ImgTile" and "ImgPath" to stay a correct position.Just do it like them.

Answer (score 0):

```
use below Code


   <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/reportRealtiveLayout02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
           <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/reportLocNameLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Name: "
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/reportLocNameValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/reportLocNameLabel"/>

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/reportLocLatLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Lat: "
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android.layout_below="@+id/reportLocNameLabel"/>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/reportLocLatValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android.layout_below="@+id/reportLocNameValue"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/reportLocLatLabel"/>

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/reportLocLngLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Lng: "
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android.layout_below="@+id/reportLocNameLabel"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/reportLocLngValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android.layout_below="@+id/reportLocLatValue"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/reportLocLngLabel"/>

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/reportTimeLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Time: "
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android.layout_below="@+id/reportLocLngLabel"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/reportTimeValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android.layout_below="@+id/reportLocLngValue"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/reportTimeLabel"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```